# nHibernate set column value when entity is changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I need to set date column with current date time whenever related entity or table has been updated using nHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interceptors as described here http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors

The example given on this page will solve your problem if you use the event "OnFlushDirty"